# Code Analysis Failure: File.separator used for regular expression

Tags: java

I have a code analysis tool that if flagging the File.separator in the below method and raising it as a critical issue. I don't understand how to implement the suggested fix, any ideas?

**Correctness - File.separator used for regular expression**
The code here uses File.separator where a regular expression is required. This will fail on Windows platforms, where the File.separator is a backslash, which is interpreted in a regular expression as an escape character. Amoung other options, you can just use File.separatorChar=='\' & "\\" : File.separator instead of File.separator

```
 private LinkedHashSet<String> process(Set<String> directoryList) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> fullSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (String i : directoryList) {
      String[] str = i.split(File.separator);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (String s : str) {
        sb.append(s);
        fullSet.add(sb.toString());
        sb.append(File.separator);
      }
    }
    return fullSet;
  }
```

Comment: Your question has explanation, why `File.separator` is not standard for regex. It differ on the basis OS.

Comment: The value of ``File.separator`` differs on each platform and the value is provided by the VM. That means that your regex looks different on each platform. While that's not a bad thing for UNIX ('/') and Windows ('\'), it might cause problems on other, exotic VMs/OSs/FileSystems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is pretty clear, but in detail the issue is the following:

When your code is run on windows `File.separator` is `\`, so

```
i.split(File.separator);
```

reads

```
i.split("\\");
```

`split()` takes a regular expression as an argument, but `\` is not a regular expression (note that the String literal `"\\"` in java results in a one-character-String with only `'\'`), as the backsla sh is the escape character so your code will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar), everything is under control.

> On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\\'.

If you put '\\' in a [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) it will be treated as a backslash, just like you expected.

Comment: Not really true. '\\' in Java code just means "\". Backslash needs to be escaped in Java and in regex expressions. Thus File.separator in Windows would need an escape back slash for a regexp. And if you want to write the whole statement, you'd need a `i.split("\\\\")` to achieve a regexp of "\\" which then would match a single \

Answer (score 1):

Java doc for `File.separatorChar()`

> This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value
> of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of
> this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\\'

It clearly suggests that for windows `\` will be treated as `\\` which you can use in your regular expression as it will not be treated as a special character.

Answer (score 0):

I used the "`\\`" finally, but I don't know what to do if the code is on Unix.

Comment: I'm assuming using a private static final String SLASH_PATTERN = Pattern.quote(System.getProperty("file.separator")); is sufficient.